# Creating an insert trigger on views

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer, oracle-xe

My table definitions look like this:

[image]

I've created a view as:

```
users_questions(qid,username,question)
```

I want to create an instead of trigger on the view which puts the data
going to be inserted on the view to the table question.

I've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON USERS_QUESTIONS
  FOR EACH ROW AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO questions(qid,question)
    VALUES (:NEW.qid,:NEW.question);
END TRIGGER1;
```

It says something like:

> Error report - ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
>   04079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
>   *Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
>   *Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.

Tried this also.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON USERS_QUESTIONS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO questions(qid,question)
      SELECT qid,question FROM inserted;
END;
```

Error:

> Error(4,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(5,32): PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I am using:

- Oracle OracleXE112
- sqldeveloper-18.2.0.183.1748

Comment: I think you need to just remove `as` after `for each row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error “Table or view does not exists” (at your second try) is caused by the `SELECT qid,question FROM inserted;` - As far as i can see, there’s no `inserted` table in your question. Is this table/view yours? Or it’s another user’s?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually its inbuilt table.